# how to ON the only Display Light (not any action on any view) when the application is idle On touch in Android

Tags: java, android

When the phone is idle, the screen turns off after the configured time. For ex: if time is set to 30 sec, first the screen will dim after approximately 25 seconds and then after 5 seconds it will turn off the screen completely.

If screen light is dim then how to disable all 'clickListener' or 'touchListener' and only perform screen lights on.

Comment: Please explain the requirement a little more clearly.. All i can't understand what is already in place and what is not working? :(

Comment: ok.. if you open any application in your device ...and after that you left your device for some time then the devise is in Idle state .  so that time  firstly the display light of your devise getting Dim ..and after few seconds display light is fully off.    So My requirement is that when devise light getting dim , that time if I touch the screen than only light is full On ... not the perform any action like button Action ...

Comment: You want to consume the touch event and just want to make light on , and avoid anything else due to touch action?